# How to disable the SonarQube rule which conflicts with the parameter of a Vuex mutation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sonarqube, vuex

While implementing a mutation as part of a Vuex store module I get the following SonarQube conflict:

`"state" hides or potentially hides a variable declared in an outer scope at line X`

The code looks similair to this code snippet from the Vuex docs:

```
const moduleA = {
  state: { count: 0 },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      // `state` is the local module state
      state.count++
    }
  }
}
```

(https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)

Is the implementation bad practice? Or do I need a special configuration / plugin for SonarQube analyse Vue / Vuex correctly?